# Get JSON data from external URL and insert in a div as plain text

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, yql

I have written a function to display some paragraph tags from an external webpage. For some reason the results are displayed in firebug console but not showing on the web page as I wanted (blank page).

```
function requestCrossDomain(callback){
  var querylink = "select * from html where url='http://somedomain.com'" +  
                     " and xpath='/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/dl'";
  var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + 
                encodeURIComponent(querylink) + '&format=json&callback?';

  $.getJSON(yql, function(data){
    if (typeof callback === 'function'){
      callback(data);
      }
   });
}
```

My firebug console shows the below value.

```
{"query":{"count":1,"created":"2013-12-23T06:31:46Z","lang":"en-US","results":{"dd":{"p":"Hills: High"}}}}
```

How can I modify the code to display the value of the P tag, which is "Hills: High"

I'm calling the function from HTML code and trying to display the value inside "#targetWrapper"

```
requestCrossDomain(function(results){
  $('#targetWrapper').html(results);
});
```

Comment: what do you expect ? that callback(data) triggers requestCrossDomain(?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited to reflect a functional [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9DaL/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  requestCrossDomain();
});

function requestCrossDomain(){
  var querylink = "select * from html where url='http://www.bom.gov.au/wa/forecasts" +  
                  "/armadale.shtml' and xpath='/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div" +  
                  "/div/dl'";   

  var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' +
             encodeURIComponent(querylink) + '&format=json&callback?';

  $.getJSON(yql, function(data){
    $('#targetWrapper').html(data.query.results.dl.dd[0].p);
    $("#targetWrapper").append("<br/><strong>" + JSON.stringify(data) + "</strong>");
  });
}
```

Your data format was very much off the mark AND you cannot have two functions with the same name.

Comment: I'm still new to javascript. Can't display the info even after changing the code as you mentioned. Please view my code here http://jsfiddle.net/landy90/pdF3e/2/

Answer (score 0):

The object you get back from `$.getJSON` is a simple [Javascript Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). You can access it just as you would any other object:

In this case, you'd use:

```
requestCrossDomain(function(results) {
    $("#targetWrapper").html(results.query.results.dd.p);
}
```

I would highly recommend that you read the MDN documentation I linked above. Having MDN bookmarked is also a good idea; it's a great resource to have easy access to.

Comment: I tried modifying the result as you suggested but still get a blank page. Please view the code here jsfiddle.net/landy90/L9DaL/

Comment: I also get an error saying that "TypeError: data.query.results.dd is undefined"

Comment: @user2574948, that's because your data format is very off the mark.  Check my updated answer.